# Finding the incentre, circumcentre of a triangle.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I am trying to discover another type of geometry. I want to transform a geometry problem to a coordinate geometry problem as a coordinate geometry problem that is easier than a pure geometry (Euclidean geometry) problem. A geometry problem needs deep thinking (I am telling about hard problems i.e. Olympiad level problems), but a coordinate geometry problem doesn't need deep thinking ,it just needs calculations. So, let us go to the original problem.

> The vertices of a  triangle $ABC$ are $(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2),(a_3,b_3)$. Find the following coordinates:
>
> $1)$ Incentre
>
> $2)$ Circumcentre
>
> $3)$ Orthocentre
>
> $4)$ Centre of the nine point circle

Please tell me with good explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There are well known formula for the [triangle centers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_center) in [trilinear coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_coordinates) $x : y : z$,

$$\begin{array}{rc:c}
\text{name} & & x : y : z \\
\hline
\text{incenter} & I & 1 : 1 : 1\\
\text{circumcenter} & O & \cos A : \cos B : \cos C\\
\text{orthocenter} & H & \sec A : \sec B :\sec C\\
\text{nine-point center} & N & \cos(B-C) : \cos(C-A) : \cos(A-B)
\end{array}
$$
You can convert them to Cartesian coordinates by the recipe:
$$P = (x,y,z) \quad \leftrightarrow \quad \vec{P} = \frac{ax \vec{A} + by\vec{B} + cz\vec{C}}{ax + by + cz}$$

In terms of coordinates, this means

$$\vec{P} = (p_1,p_2) = 
\left(
\frac{ax a_1 + by a_2 + cz a_3}{ax + by + cz},
\frac{ax b_1 + by b_2 + cz b_3}{ax + by + cz}
\right)
$$
The parameters $a,b,c$ and $A,B,C$ are given by the formula:
$$\begin{cases}
a &= \sqrt{(a_2-a_3)^2 + (b_2 - b_3)^2}\\
b &= \sqrt{(a_3-a_1)^2 + (b_3 - b_1)^2}\\
c &= \sqrt{(a_1-a_2)^2 + (b_1 - b_2)^2}
\end{cases}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\begin{cases}
A &= \cos^{-1}\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}\\
B &= \cos^{-1}\frac{c^2+a^2-b^2}{2ca}\\
C &= \cos^{-1}\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}
\end{cases}
$$
The parameters $x, y, z$ can be obtained by plugging these expressions of $a,b,c, A,B,C$ into corresponding formula in above table.

Comment: @achilille hui I want the coordinate not the trilinear coordinate.I need the Cartesian coordinate .So please tell me the right way

Comment: Thanks for the great write-up. In the equation defining c, I think that $b_2 - b_3$ should be replaced by $b_1 - b_2$.

Comment: @Alex338207 yes, that's a typo, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

"Formulas in Cartesian coordinates using determinants"

"The vertices of triangle ABC are A=(xA,yA), B=(xB,yB) e C=(xC,yC)"

"Circumcenter (K)"

$xK=\frac{1}{2D}\left| \begin{array}{} xA^2+yA^2 & yA & 1 \\ xB^2+yB^2 & yB & 1 \\ xC^2+yC^2 & yC & 1 \\ \end{array} \right| $

$yK=\frac{-1}{2D}\left| \begin{array}{} xA^2+yA^2 & xA & 1 \\ xB^2+yB^2 & xB & 1 \\ xC^2+yC^2 & xC & 1 \\ \end{array} \right|$

$D=\left|\begin{array}{} xA & yA & 1 \\ xB & yB & 1 \\ xC & yC & 1 \\ \end{array}  \right|$

"Incenter"

$xI=\frac{a.xA+b.xB+c.xC}{a+b+c}$

$yI=\frac{a.yA+b.yB+c.yC}{a+b+c}$

$a=\sqrt{(xB-xC)^2+(yB-yC)^2}$

$b=\sqrt{(xC-xA)^2+(yC-yA)^2}$

$c=\sqrt{(xA-xB)^2+(yA-yB)^2}$

Comment: Portuguese, maybe?